# Serialize SparkR DataFrame to jobj

Tags: r, apache-spark, cassandra, sparkr, sparklyr

I'd like to be able to use the Java methods on a SparkR SparkDataFrame to write data to Cassandra.

Using the `sparklyr` extensions for example, I can do something like this:

```
sparklyr::invoke(sparklyr::spark_dataframe(spark_tbl), "write") %>>% 
sparklyr::invoke("format", "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") %>>% 
sparklyr::invoke("option", "keyspace", keyspace) %>>% 
sparklyr::invoke("option", "table", table) %>>%
sparklyr::invoke("mode", "append") %>% 
sparklyr::invoke("save")
```

which can achieve a write speed of around 20k rows a second.

For my use case, however, I'd like to be able to use `SparkR::spark.lapply` so I can collect subsets of my Cassandra table locally, run a script on them and write the data back. Every method I've tried using `sparklyr` has ended up single threaded, and so not utilising spark at all really.

With `SparkR`, I can write the data using something like:

```
SparkR::saveDF(SparkR::as.DataFrame(dt_local), "",
               source = "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra",
               table = table,
               keyspace = keyspace,
               mode = "append")
```

however the write speed is closer to 2k rows per second in this case. I think I would be able to use `SparkR::sparkR.callJMethod` to call the same chain as in the `sparklyr` case to achieve the higher write speed, however I'd first need to serialize the `SparkDataFrame` such that have a handle to a `jobj` which I haven't been able to do. Is this possible?

I'm also open to any other methods of achieving this if possible. I've investigated trying to move between `sparkR` and `sparklyr` but it seems the backends are too different (as far as I know). I also believe from [here](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/81) that there's no analogous `lapply` for `sparklyr` as of yet.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short it is not possible. Apache Spark doesn't support, and most likely will never support, nested parallelized operations. This is not related to a particular backend. You could try to use `SparkR::*apply` methods with native R clients (`dbConnect`, `RCassandra`).

You can access JVM object:

```
SparkR::as.DataFrame(dt_local)@sdf
```

but it simply cannot be used outside the driver node.